# Angularjs - variable not found

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

have this issue with Angular.js that I can't seem to fix.
Here is my simple `html`:

```
<html ng-app="myAngularapp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myangular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="myAngularCtrl">
<form ng-submit="addingName()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="myAngular.newname"  size="30"
               placeholder="add new todo here">
        <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
      </form>
</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

and `myangular.js`:

```
angular.module("myAngularapp",[])
    .controller("myAngularCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.myNames = [
            {name:"aaa"},
            {name:"aaa"},
            {name:"aaa"}
        ];

        $scope.addingName = function(){
            $scope.myNames.push({name:newname});
        }
    });
```

When I press the submit button, I got an error:

> Error: Can't find variable: newname

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Hi, what is **myAngular**. Do you mean it to represent your controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never declared `newname`, instead it's a property on the `$scope`

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myAngular.newname"  size="30">
```

Can be accessed by `$scope.myAngular.newname`, not `newname` in your controller.

```
$scope.myNames.push({name: $scope.myAngular.newname});
```

This is because angular stores variables that can be accessed by the HTML in the `$scope`. This is an object that can be accessed inside a controller, making it unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `myAngular.newname` in the controller:

```
$scope.myAngular.newname
```

Or another option is to add an argument to `addingName`:

```
$scope.addingName = function(newname){//ur code};
```

Then change the HTML:

```
ng-submit="addingName(myAngular.newname)"
```

Answer (score 0):

In you html you are binding your input to a model called `myAngular.newname`
But when you add this value to your array myNames you are using a variable `newname`.

You can either change variable name in your view or in your controller. This is up to you.

One option to fix your problem is:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myAngular.newname"  size="30"
               placeholder="add new todo here">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
this.myAngular.newname
```

for getting value of text box after submitting the form

http://plnkr.co/edit/6P5LXuuTAfUfQS4RxmWG?p=preview

Comment: Please put full code here, on Stack Overflow, with an explanation of why and how the code works. If you paste a link that stops working in the future, then your answer is lost, it's also super helpful to not have to go to a separate page. And, just spoon-feeding answers never helps anyone - you should explain how the code you gave fixes the the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice: ViewModel should be very clearly defined.

Always use `Controller As` syntax and avoid $scope.

```
<form ng-submit="addingName()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myAngular.newname"  size="30"
                   placeholder="add new todo here">
    <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

As you are using `myAngular.newname`, it should be declared on VM (`$scope` in your case). and pass the parameter of newname in the `addingName` function

So, your JS would be:

```
angular.module("myAngularapp",[])
    .controller("myAngularCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.myNames = [
            {name:"aaa"},
            {name:"aaa"},
            {name:"aaa"}
        ];

        //or you may use without myAngular
        //$scope.newname = "";
        //in this case you will have to use: ng-model="newname"
        //                        instead of ng-model="myAngular.newname"
        $scope.myAngular = {
            newname: ""
        };

        $scope.addingName = addName;

        //you can use addName function even to add names from JS itself also
        function addName(name){
            $scope.myNames.push({name});
        }
    });
```

and view would be:

```
<form ng-submit="addingName(myAngular.newname)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myAngular.newname"  size="30"
                   placeholder="add new todo here">
    <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

**PS**: *I can not add comments, so listed all the best practices as separate answer.*